# Android: How to copy a file from existing Uri?

Tags: android, uri

I have an Uri in my Android app and I would like to copy the file represented by it to the same destination, but with a different name.

For example, if my file 'test.txt' is on external storage, how can I get test.txt_copy on the exact same location ?

Here is what I did:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 44444);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (44444 == requestCode) {
        if (null != data) {
            final Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (null != uri) {
                try {
                    final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                    final int fileSize = bis.available();
                    final byte[] rawFile = new byte[fileSize];
                    int read = bis.read(rawFile, 0, fileSize);
                    bis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to extend your [mcve] to show exactly what you are doing to get the value of `uri`.

Comment: Sorry, my post wasn't clear enough. I edited my code for you to reproduce my example.

Comment: While you have read (and probably write) access to the content that the user chooses, you do not have any rights to anything else, including whatever sort of directory or other document tree that happens to contain the content that the user chose. You might consider using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to have the user choose (and grant you rights to use) a document tree, then work within there.

Comment: When I use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, I get this exception: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* }

Comment: That looks like you did not construct the `Intent` correctly. Remove `OPENABLE` and the MIME type. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/09/scoped-storage-stories-trees.html) for more on how to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to do what you suggest, however, how do I get the user to choose a file specifically as ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE lets me pick a folder, not a file. Or maybe I misunderstood something...

Comment: You will need to ask the user for the source content (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`) and the destination (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`). You can then copy the content from the source to the destination tree.

Comment: I think I got it now. So it is basically impossible to do it with only one Intent. After choosing destination path, should I use uri.buildUpon().appendPath("myfile").build() ?

Comment: "So it is basically impossible to do it with only one Intent" -- correct. "should I use uri.buildUpon().appendPath("myfile").build()?" -- no, sorry. Use `DocumentFile`, as I discuss in [the blog post that I linked to](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/09/scoped-storage-stories-trees.html). Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to wrap the `Uri` you get back from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. Call `createFile()` on the `DocumentFile` for the tree to create a `DocumentFile` for your copy. Call `getUri()` on *that* `DocumentFile` to get the value to pass to `openOutputStream()` on `ContentResolver`.